# flipping a tile in android

Tags: android, animation, nineoldandroids

In my layout, I am having a set of tiles(Something similar to windows phone home screen) .I am trying to flip the tile to show more content. I have taken a look at card flipping, but then it flips the entire fragment.I want it to flip a part of the whole layout.I have tried rotating it using Object animator .Here is my code..

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.iotd_relative);
            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
            animation.setDuration(3600);
            animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.start();
```

Is there any possibility of calling another layout when it flips?

Comment: I have the same requirement can you tell me the approach what layout and architecture you used for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a ScaleAnimation, heres a good example that simulates a Card Flip, you should be able to get what you want from there.

[Use Android's scale animation to simulate a 3D flip...](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-scale-animation-to-simulate-a-3d-flip/)

Comment: It says the page doesnot exist..Could you please check the link?